# Getting the details like email, phone number from the textarea using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a textarea with ng-model="address". I am getting the value of address. My question is, i want to read the email, phone number, name from that textarea using the angular js.

please provide the answer before marking it as duplicate or question down. Any help will be greatfull.

Comment: what you have done so far???

Comment: hi @Darshak. I have tried to get those using the regular expression

Comment: @Darshak i think you don't understand my question. I want to get the email, contact number from the textarea but not from the separate fields.

Comment: means you have one textarea and in that you have email,phone number and name text..right?

Comment: if possible..create one fiddler..

Comment: you should show the regex you have tried so far? Are you expecting a pattern?

Comment: what do you want really ? and what have you done so far ?

Comment: I have an customer address with phone number and email id which i will paste it in the textarea. Now i want to extract those mail and phone number from the textarea using angular js. I have try to extract those data using js with regular expression